# Bedeutung von "sensibel" in "Medikamente wurden für die Therapie als sensibel getestet."

Tags: meaning

Das Original lautet

> Die Behandlung dieser besonderen Form der MDR-TB setzt voraus, dass
>   aus der Palette der antituberkulös wirksamen Medikamente noch
>   mindestens fünf für die Therapie als sensibel getestet wurden.

Ist das Wort "sensibel" hier falsch gebraucht? Ist es ein bloßer Sprachfehler oder eine der "Sprachdummheiten in der Medizin"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das ist Fachsprache. Anzuchten reagieren auf Antibiotika entweder *sensibel*, *intermediär* oder *resistent*.

Die Formulierung ist ungeschickt, denn es wurden ja nicht die Medikamente als sensibel getestet, sondern die Bakterien als sensibel gegen das Medikament. Eine bessere Formulierung wird dann von den Fachleuten aber nicht mehr zuverlässig verstanden.